# Trying to understand the proof of Theorem $9.4.1$ from Effros-Ruan book

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem  $9.4.1$ from the book titled Operator spaces by Effros Ruan.

> Let A and $B$ be unital $C^{\ast}$-algebras then a linear functional $F: A \otimes^h B \to \mathbb{C}$ is bounded if and only if there exist unital $^{\ast}$-representations $\Pi_A: A\to B(H)$ and $\Pi_B : B \to B(K)$, vector $\zeta \in H$ and $\eta \in K$ and a bounded linear operator $T: K \to H$ such that $F( a \otimes b)=\langle \Pi_A(a)T\Pi_B(b) \eta, \zeta \rangle_H$

The proof goes as follows

> If $F: A \otimes B \to \mathbb{C}$ is a linear functional satisfying the given condition, then for any $a=[a_1,...,a_r] \in M_{1,r}(A)$ and $b=[b_1,...,b_r]^T \in M_{r,1}(B)$ we have

\begin{align*}
    \vert F( a \odot b) \vert &= \vert \sum F(a_i \otimes b_i) \vert \\
    &= \vert \sum \langle \Pi_A(a_i)T \Pi_B(b_i)\eta, \zeta \rangle \vert \\
    &=\vert \langle (\Pi_A)_{1,r}(a)(I_r \otimes T)(\Pi_B)_{r,1}(b)\eta , \zeta \rangle \vert
    \end{align*}

> Can someone please explain me how does one obtains the last line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line is a condensed way of writing
\begin{align*}
\sum_j\Pi_A(a_j)T\Pi_B(b_j)
&=\begin{bmatrix} \Pi_A(a_1)&\cdots &\Pi_A(a_r)\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} T\\ & \ddots\\ && T\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Pi_B(b_1)\\ \vdots\\ \Pi_B(b_r)\end{bmatrix}\\[0.3cm]
&=(\Pi_A)_{1,r}(a)\,\begin{bmatrix} T\\ & \ddots\\ && T\end{bmatrix} (\Pi_B)_{r,1}(b).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much.